# Stuck on boot screen

Tags: dual-boot, budgie

I am using Ubuntu budgie and it was working file till today morning. I don't usually shut down my laptop at all but yesterday as my battery drained completely so after I charged it, I tried booting it up. After start grub my Ubuntu logo appeared and later a black screen with some nerdy texts was visible and every time I boot it is stuck to that process.

[image: Boot screen image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try booting into recovery mode and running fsck.  fsck check and repairs (if necessary) your filesystem.  Shut down your computer, then boot.  During the boot, hold down the shift key so that the grub menu is shown. Select the “Advanced options”.

[image]

Then choose “Recovery mode”.

[image]

In the next menu select “fsck”.

[image]

You will be asked if you wish to have your / filesystem remounted. Select “yes”.

[image]

You should see something similar to this.

[image]

You can then resume to normal boot, by selecting “Resume”.

[image]

Select Normal Boot

Instructions taken from this site, where there is more information available: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/